# Shared folder DNS shortname "randomly" stops resolving on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, network-share

I'm running your standard Domain set up - AD with DNS and a RDS server.

On the RDS server, I've mapped some drives to a local NAS using the DNS shortname...

\\folders\sharedfolder

\\folders is a static DNS entry on the AD server.

"Randomly" it starts throwing the error "Windows cannot access \\folders"

I can:

ping folders

nslookup folders (connects to local DNS server and returns the proper IP)

connect by ip address \\192.168.1.111\sharefolder

connect by FQDN \\folders.domain.com\sharedfolder

but I cannot use \\folders\sharedfolders again until I restart the RDS server.

net view \\folders = System error 53 has occured.

Thing is, I restarted the server Saturday afternoon for the problem and now it's Monday morning and right back to it!

Comment: doesn't sound like DNS based on the steps you can reproduce.  Is the drive mapping manual or through a script?  Is the account logging in the same across multiple RDS sessions?

Comment: drive mapping is manual; happens when trying to manually access also.  The shared folder has "domain users" permissions, so yes, multiple users on the RDS server are accessing the same share.

Comment: I meant, is it "domain\user1" logging in to RDS multiple times (shared account) and accessing the share through multiple sessions?

Comment: No, all users have their own account.  The hostname of the NAS is not "folders", I just manually created that dns entry / hostname.  Curious if that's related.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have a GPO or other automated process that is changing the DNS Search Suffix. By default, when you do an unqualified lookup, Windows will try to append a domain suffix to it and do a lookup. It sounds to me like something is changing that suffix at an automated interval.

Comment: he can ping the short name (and I'm assuming here) and resolve to the right IP.  Sounds like DNS isn't the issue from what he's describing.  Possibly more along the lines of the sessions getting mixed up in the server that is hosting the share?

Comment: Yeah, oops. Definitely missed that.